# Returning SQL query from a Hapi.js route handler function (javascript callback help)

Tags: node.js, sqlite, callback, hapi.js

So I have created a Hapi.js restful application. The backend is connected to a SQlite3 database. When the user throws a GET request to any arbitrary endpoint, in this case '/employees,' I am having trouble returning the information obtained from the SQL query to the user with my current callback situation.

Here is my current code:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/employees',
    handler: function(request, h) {
        var employees = [];
        db.all('SELECT * from Employee;',[], function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (rows) {
                rows.forEach(elt => {
                    employees.push(elt);
                });
            } 

        }, () => {
            return employees.toString();
        });
     }
    // hapi requires me to return a value or promise here
});
```

Right now the above code is failing because I am not returning anything at the end of the handler function. I am getting rows from my sql query but am having trouble figuring out how to return that information in the response due to my callback structure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you are not using `db.all()` the right way…
According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseallsql-param--callback), it seems that `db.all` take a callback and not two like you do…

Pretty sure your code is failing because you return in a callback that is never used...

You should try something like that:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/employees',
    handler: function(request, h) {
        db.all('SELECT * from Employee;',[], function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return err;
            }

            return rows;
        });
     }
});
```

This is a wild guess, I have never used Sqlite3 nor Hapi17 but I am pretty confident. Can you please confirm that it is working and keep my mind at peace ?